# Can't update my ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 because "Internet connection failed"

Tags: updates, 14.10, update-manager

I want to update my ubuntu system to 14.10 but my software updater tells me that it isn't connected to the internet, even though I can use my browser, thunderbird etc. When I retry and restart the program, it tells me the same. Occasionally it tells me that there are no updates (for other programs available) and asks me if I want to update my version of ubuntu. If I select "update" I get the prompt for my password but afterwards nothing happens.

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in the terminal, but I get *mistake 404* not found for some of the packages.

This is the end of the code I get, the rest seems to work and it would have been to much to paste it here:

```
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/eckert-georg/kawaiki/ubuntu    /dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/eckert-georg/kawaiki/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsvh/pacifica-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsvh/pacifica-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

It's in German, but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Would you please post the exact outputs (edit your answer and use code formatting)? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can see, it doesn't say Internet connection fails, only `404  Not Found`, the added ppa's are not available (any more?)

Comment: Okay. But what should I do? Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the package isn't available in your version of Ubuntu. You can go to the `Other Software` tab in `Software & Updates` and unselect the PPA's which are causing the error.

Try running `apt-get update` to confirm.